# Minimizing DirectX 10 Window on Alt Tab

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-10

I've been trying to get my DirectX 10 application to properly handle alt tabbing from full screen. When I alt tab from full screen, the application automatically goes into windowed mode.

I tried listening for WM_ACTIVATEAPP to manually minimize and maximize the program. It works, but it breaks other functionality in the program that was already working (toggling between full screen and windowed). The first time I attempt to toggle out of full screen after having restored from alt tab, a black screen flashes and it stays in full screen, the second time it triggers WM_ACTIVATEAPP causing the entire program to be minimized instead of properly going in to windowed mode.

Below is the code I am using:

On WM_SIZE:

```
mD3D->ResizeBuffers(width, height);
mBufferWidth = width;
mBufferHeight = height;
mViewport.SetViewportRect(0, 0, width, height);
mD3D->GetDevice()->RSSetViewports(1, &mViewport.GetViewport());
```

On WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

```
if(wParam == TRUE && mSwapChainDesc.Windowed == FALSE)
{
  // Restore
  ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
  mSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(TRUE, NULL);
  mSwapChainDesc.Windowed = FALSE;
  ResizeBuffers(mBufferWidth, mBufferHeight);
}
else if(wParam == FALSE && mSwapChainDesc.Windowed == FALSE)
{
  // Minimize
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE);
  mSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);
  ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);
}
```

On toggle windowed mode request:

```
if(mSwapChainDesc.Windowed)
{
  mSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(TRUE, NULL);
  mSwapChainDesc.Windowed = FALSE;
}
else
{
  mSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);
  mSwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
}
ResizeBuffers(mBufferWidth, mBufferHeight);
```

ResizeBuffers:

```
mDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);

// Release all outstanding references to the swap chain's buffers.
mRenderTargetView->Release();

HRESULT hr;
// Preserve the existing buffer count and format.
// Automatically choose the width and height to match the client rect for HWNDs.
hr = mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, width, height, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);

// Get buffer and create a render-target-view.
ID3D10Texture2D* pBuffer;
hr = mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof( ID3D10Texture2D), (void**) &pBuffer );

hr = mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBuffer, NULL, &mRenderTargetView);
pBuffer->Release();

mDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &mRenderTargetView, NULL );

// Set up the viewport.
D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;
vp.Width = width;
vp.Height = height;
vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
vp.TopLeftX = 0;
vp.TopLeftY = 0;
mDevice->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );
```

How can I minimize the window and still maintain the ability to toggle between windowed and full screen with DirectX 10?

Comment: Are you making d3d calls from your windows message handler? I can't recall where I saw it :) but I don't think that's a good idea. You should defer your calls (set a variable or something) and perform them outside your handler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's deferred through a messaging system.

Comment: I don't think you need to response message WM_ACTIVATEAPP, what's that for?

Comment: @zdd: I think that was the way to handle alt-tab back in pre-directx-9 days. With DirectX9 or DirectX 10 interfaces, you normally don't even need to care about this, it should just work. But honestly, I haven't ever been using DirectX 10 in full screen mode.

Comment: Have you tried using WM_ACTIVATE instead, and processing the wparam. It shouldn't break anything. I've used it before and I don't remember breaking anything.

Comment: Which flags are you using with your DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC? Be sure to read through [DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI): Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025(v=vs.85).aspx)